# how can I monitor an FTP server without the SNMP protoocl

Tags: java, snmp

I have developed an FTP server in java that allows the upload and the download of files,my problem is that I want to monitor this server with the SNMP protocol,but the SNMP talk didn't help me I didn't found any information in my files concerning the FTP server(CPU,memory...)
is there any other way to monitor pro-grammatically an FTP server and thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All kinds. There's something called JMX just for monitoring java type thingies. You might guess that I don't know much about it.

You could also create a listener model inside your server and allow subscriptions from outside and monitor what pleases you.